# Button click in javascript doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, button, cordova

i'm writing a function to save the image after editing like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function share() {      
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

          var imageObj = new Image();

          imageObj.onload = function() {
            contentW = $("#content").width();
            canvas.width = 400;
            canvas.height = 600;
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            //the plugin
            setTimeout(function(){
            window.savephotoplugin(canvas,"image/png",device.version,function(val){ 
                    //returns you the saved path in val 
                    alert("Photo Saved: " + val);   
                });
            },0) 
        }           
        }              
</script>
```

button code

```
 <div >  
 <IMG SRC="loadin.png" ALT="some text" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100>
 <button class="button" id="myCanvas" onclick="share()">SEND </button>
 </div>
```

but after button click no event is fired in phonegap app. my code is correct even the logcat output is without error, but why am not getting output? please help me

Comment: You're using imageObj.onload which is never triggered. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `img.onload`, it may not fire for cached images. But you can add some random value to img src, e.g.

```
<img src="path/to/pic.jpg?r=1381257249" />
```

And i can't see you appending created `imageObj` to DOM, no events will fire for it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, now onclick of button responds, but i'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined" this error after removing img.onload. any idea on this? @Arty Gus

Comment: @dd what's `device` variable or.. can you please post the full code jsfiddle?

Comment: make sure you have the device plugin installed